# How to paint inside a set of lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, mathcha

I drew this stator figure on Mathcha and I do not know how to paint the white part. The slot contour was made by a set of lines. How can I paint inside them? If I group the lines and paint inside them the result is the below:

[image]

How can I paint all the stator correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post your Latex code so far? It should contain the `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` so that people can try and help you easier.

Answer (score 12):

It's difficult to say without knowing your code, but I'm assuming you need something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

% isometric axes
\pgfmathsetmacro\xx{1/sqrt(2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xy{1/sqrt(6)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zz{sqrt(2/3)}
\tikzset{isometric/.style={x={(-\xx cm,-\xy cm)},y={(\xx cm,-\xy cm)},z={(0cm,\zz cm)}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric,line join=round,line cap=round]
% cogs side walls (not all of them visible)
\foreach\i in{1,...,32} 
  \draw[fill=gray!50] (11.25*\i:2) -- (11.25*\i:1.5) --++ (0,0,0.25) --++ (11.25*\i:0.5) -- cycle;
% inner part
\draw[fill=gray!30] (135:1.5) foreach\i in {135,157.5,...,270}
  {arc (\i:\i+11.25:1.5)  --++ (0,0,0.25) arc (\i+11.25:\i+22.5:1.5) --++ (0,0,-0.25)} 
   arc (292.5:303.75:1.5) --++ (0,0,0.25) arc (303.75:315:1.5)       --++ (0,0, 0.75)
   arc (315:135:1.5) -- cycle;
% outer part
\draw[fill=gray!10] (-45:2) foreach\i in {-45,-22.5,...,101.25}
  {arc (\i:\i+11.25:2)  --++ (0,0,0.25) arc (\i+11.25:\i+22.5:2) --++ (0,0,-0.25)} 
   arc (112.5:123.75:2) --++ (0,0,0.25) arc (123.75:135:2)       --++ (0,0, 0.75)
    arc (135:-45:2) -- cycle;
% top part
\draw[even odd rule,fill=gray!20] (0,0,1) circle (2) (0,0,1) circle (1.5); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I divided the central angle (360) in 32 parts of 11.25 degrees each. Then I move between cogs with a `foreach` both in the inner and the outer side. As you can see this is a 3d drawing with isometric perspective, but it can be accomplished in a similar way in 2d using ellipses.

**Edit 1:** If you want to draw only the visible cogs, substitute the first `\foreach` for

```
\foreach\i in{1,3,6,8,10,12,16,18,21,23,25,29,31} % only visible cogs
  \draw[fill=gray!50] (11.25*\i:2) -- (11.25*\i:1.5) --++ (0,0,0.25) --++ (11.25*\i:0.5) -- cycle;
```

**Edit 2:** Another example with 24 cogs (removed).

**Edit 3:** A more customizable version:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

% isometric axes
\pgfmathsetmacro\xx{1/sqrt(2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xy{1/sqrt(6)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zz{sqrt(2/3)}
\tikzset{isometric/.style={x={(-\xx cm,-\xy cm)},y={(\xx cm,-\xy cm)},z={(0cm,\zz cm)}}}

% parameters
\def\nc{24}   % number of cogs (multiple of 4, at least 8)
\def\H {1}    % total height
\def\h {0.25} % cog height
\def\R {2}    % outer radius
\def\r {1.5}  % inner radius

\pgfmathtruncatemacro\nw{\nc/4} % number of cog walls per quadrant
\pgfmathsetmacro\a {180/\nc}    % step angle
\pgfmathsetmacro\is{135+2*\a}   % inner part step
\pgfmathsetmacro\il{315-4*\a}   % inner part last iteration
\pgfmathsetmacro\os{-45+2*\a}   % outer part step
\pgfmathsetmacro\ol{135-4*\a}   % outer part last iteration

\tikzset
{
  inner/.style={fill=blue!35},
  outer/.style={fill=blue!15},
  cogs/.style= {fill=blue!60},
  top/.style=  {fill=blue!20},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric,line join=round,line cap=round]
% inner cogs side walls
\foreach\i in{-\nw,...,\nw}
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\j{4*\nw-\i}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\k{6*\nw+\i}
  \draw[cogs] (\a*\j:\R) -- (\a*\j:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\j:\R-\r) -- cycle;
  \draw[cogs] (\a*\k:\R) -- (\a*\k:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\k:\R-\r) -- cycle;
}
% inner part
\draw[inner] (135:\r) foreach\i in {135,\is,...,\il}
  {arc (\i:\i+\a:\r)        --++ (0,0,\h) arc (\i+\a:\i+2*\a:\r) --++ (0,0,-\h)}
   arc (315-2*\a:315-\a:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) arc (315-\a:315:\r)    --++ (0,0, \H-\h)
   arc (315:135:\r) -- cycle;
% outer cogs side walls
\foreach\i in{-\nw,...,\nw}
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\j{-\i+2*\nw}
  \draw[cogs] (\a*\i:\R) -- (\a*\i:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\i:\R-\r) -- cycle;
  \draw[cogs] (\a*\j:\R) -- (\a*\j:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\j:\R-\r) -- cycle;
}
% outer part
\draw[outer] (-45:\R) foreach\i in {-45,\os,...,\ol}
  {arc (\i:\i+\a:\R)        --++ (0,0,\h) arc (\i+\a:\i+2*\a:\R) --++ (0,0,-\h)}
   arc (135-2*\a:135-\a:\R) --++ (0,0,\h) arc (135-\a:135:\R)    --++ (0,0,\H-\h)
   arc (135:-45:\R) -- cycle;
% top part
\draw[even odd rule,top] (0,0,\H) circle (\R) (0,0,\H) circle (\r);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good suggestion...

Comment: @MadyYuvi, thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks! In fact your solution is better than mine! How can I change the total number of cogs from 32 to 24? It is just changing the number 32 for 24?

Comment: @FábioGregório, I'm afraid not. We need to change all the angles. My picture has 16 cogs, so we need to change 32=16*2 to 48=24*2, the step angle 11.25=360:32 to 7.5=360:48, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is a try with [Asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/).

```
import solids;

currentprojection=orthographic(1,1,0.7);
currentlight.background = gray(.5)+green;
viewportmargin=(0.5cm,0.5cm);

picture pic2;
size(pic2,300);

path[] g = {box((4.5,0),(6,2.3)),box((4.5,.7),(6,2.3))};

pen[] colors={red,green,cyan, gray};
colors.cyclic=true;

// 36 cogs
for (int j=0; j<=35; ++j)
{
  for(int i=0;i<length((j%2 == 0) ? g[0] : g[1]);++i)
  {
    path3 p=path3(subpath((j%2 == 0) ? g[0] : g[1],i,i+1),YZplane);
    path3 p_=path3(box((4.5,0),(6,.7)),YZplane);
    revolution R=revolution(p,Z,j*10,(j+1)*10);
    
    draw(pic2,surface(R),colors[i]);
    draw(pic2,rotate(j*10,Z)*surface(p_),pink); 
  }
}

add(pic2.fit());
```

[image]