# How to draw lines in a stator figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Following the question [How to paint inside a set of lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612620/how-to-paint-inside-a-set-of-lines/612658#612658), I have another doubt. How can I put the lines as the above picture:

[image]

Basically, I want to draw the images b) c) and d) redlines lines in the a) one. The b) lines cut vertically the image, the c) horizontally, and the d) circularly. Thanks!

**Edit**: The code of figure d) is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
     % isometric axes
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xx{1/sqrt(2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xy{1/sqrt(6)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\zz{sqrt(2/3)}
    \tikzset{isometric/.style={x={(-\xx cm,-\xy cm)},y={(\xx cm,-\xy cm)},z={(0cm,\zz cm)}}}
    
    % parameters
    \def\nc{24}   % number of cogs (multiple of 4, at least 8)
    \def\H {1}    % total height
    \def\h {0.25} % cog height
    \def\R {2}    % outer radius
    \def\r {1.5}  % inner radius
    
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\nw{\nc/4} % number of cog walls per quadrant
    \pgfmathsetmacro\a {180/\nc}    % step angle
    \pgfmathsetmacro\is{135+2*\a}   % inner part step
    \pgfmathsetmacro\il{315-4*\a}   % inner part last iteration
    \pgfmathsetmacro\os{-45+2*\a}   % outer part step
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ol{135-4*\a}   % outer part last iteration
    
    \tikzset
    {
      inner/.style={fill=gray!30},
      outer/.style={fill=gray!10},
      cogs/.style= {fill=gray!50},
      top/.style=  {fill=gray!20},
      cut/.style=  {color=red!60, dashed},
    }
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=1,xscale=1, isometric,line join=round,line cap=round]
    % inner cogs side walls
    \foreach\i in{-\nw,...,\nw}
    {
      \pgfmathsetmacro\j{4*\nw-\i}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\k{6*\nw+\i}
      \draw[cogs] (\a*\j:\R) -- (\a*\j:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\j:\R-\r) -- cycle;
      \draw[cogs] (\a*\k:\R) -- (\a*\k:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\k:\R-\r) -- cycle;
    }
    % inner part
    \draw[inner] (135:\r) foreach\i in {135,\is,...,\il}
      {arc (\i:\i+\a:\r)        --++ (0,0,\h) arc (\i+\a:\i+2*\a:\r) --++ (0,0,-\h)}
       arc (315-2*\a:315-\a:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) arc (315-\a:315:\r)    --++ (0,0, \H-\h)
       arc (315:135:\r) -- cycle;
    % outer cogs side walls
    \foreach\i in{-\nw,...,\nw}
    {
      \pgfmathsetmacro\j{-\i+2*\nw}
      \draw[cogs] (\a*\i:\R) -- (\a*\i:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\i:\R-\r) -- cycle;
      \draw[cogs] (\a*\j:\R) -- (\a*\j:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\j:\R-\r) -- cycle;
    }
    % outer part
    \draw[outer] (-45:\R) foreach\i in {-45,\os,...,\ol}
      {arc (\i:\i+\a:\R)        --++ (0,0,\h) arc (\i+\a:\i+2*\a:\R) --++ (0,0,-\h)}
       arc (135-2*\a:135-\a:\R) --++ (0,0,\h) arc (135-\a:135:\R)    --++ (0,0,\H-\h)
       arc (135:-45:\R) -- cycle;
    % top part
    \draw[even odd rule,top] (0,0,\H) circle (\R) (0,0,\H) circle (\r);
    \draw[even odd rule,cut] (0,0,\H) circle (0.95*\R);
    \draw[even odd rule,cut] (0,0,\H) circle (0.90*\R);
    \draw[even odd rule,cut] (0,0,\H) circle (0.85*\R);
    \draw[even odd rule,cut] (0,0,\H) circle (0.80*\R);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The d) one is pretty straightforward if you look closely to the end of Juan's code. The c) one should be also ok, using `clip`.

Comment: You forgot to include your code.

Comment: The code is already in my question.

Comment: I mean the code where YOU show what you have tried to create the above figures. I can not find that anywhere. You also do not explain what is causing you problems when trying to create the figures. Basically you want someone else to do your work.

Comment: The b) and c) figures was created in Mathcha. The a) was created by one person here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612620/how-to-paint-inside-a-set-of-lines/612658#612658. The d) I added some lines at the code of the line a). The intent of this post is not to others make the things for me, but instead give me some tips about how to do... Basically, I wanna do red lines like the b) and c) in the figure of a). I hope you understood.

Comment: Please make your code compilable, so that we easily can see the result and so that everyone has a starting point for a solution.

Comment: I think it already is.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

% isometric axes
\pgfmathsetmacro\xx{1/sqrt(2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xy{1/sqrt(6)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zz{sqrt(2/3)}
\tikzset{isometric/.style={x={(-\xx cm,-\xy cm)},y={(\xx cm,-\xy cm)},z={(0cm,\zz cm)}}}

% parameters
\def\nc{24}   % number of cogs (multiple of 4, at least 8)
\def\H {1}    % total height
\def\h {0.25} % cog height
\def\R {2}    % outer radius
\def\r {1.5}  % inner radius

\pgfmathtruncatemacro\nw{\nc/4} % number of cog walls per quadrant
\pgfmathsetmacro\a {180/\nc}    % step angle
\pgfmathsetmacro\is{135+2*\a}   % inner part step
\pgfmathsetmacro\il{315-4*\a}   % inner part last iteration
\pgfmathsetmacro\os{-45+2*\a}   % outer part step
\pgfmathsetmacro\ol{135-4*\a}   % outer part last iteration

\tikzset
{
  inner/.style={fill=gray!30},
  outer/.style={fill=gray!10},
  cogs/.style= {fill=gray!50},
  top/.style=  {fill=gray!20},
  cut/.style=  {color=red!60},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=1,xscale=1, isometric,line join=round,line cap=round]
% inner cogs side walls
\foreach\i in{-\nw,...,\nw}
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\j{4*\nw-\i}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\k{6*\nw+\i}
  \draw[cogs] (\a*\j:\R) -- (\a*\j:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\j:\R-\r) -- cycle;
  \draw[cogs] (\a*\k:\R) -- (\a*\k:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\k:\R-\r) -- cycle;
}
% inner part
\draw[inner] (135:\r) foreach\i in {135,\is,...,\il}
  {arc (\i:\i+\a:\r)        --++ (0,0,\h) arc (\i+\a:\i+2*\a:\r) --++ (0,0,-\h)}
   arc (315-2*\a:315-\a:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) arc (315-\a:315:\r)    --++ (0,0, \H-\h)
   arc (315:135:\r) -- cycle;
% outer cogs side walls
\foreach\i in{-\nw,...,\nw}
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\j{-\i+2*\nw}
  \draw[cogs] (\a*\i:\R) -- (\a*\i:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\i:\R-\r) -- cycle;
  \draw[cogs] (\a*\j:\R) -- (\a*\j:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\j:\R-\r) -- cycle;
}
% outer part
\draw[outer] (-45:\R) foreach\i in {-45,\os,...,\ol}
  {arc (\i:\i+\a:\R)        --++ (0,0,\h) arc (\i+\a:\i+2*\a:\R) --++ (0,0,-\h)}
   arc (135-2*\a:135-\a:\R) --++ (0,0,\h) arc (135-\a:135:\R)    --++ (0,0,\H-\h)
   arc (135:-45:\R) -- cycle;


% top part
\draw[even odd rule,top] (0,0,\H) circle (\R) (0,0,\H) circle (\r);

\begin{scope}
\clip (-45:\R) foreach\i in {-45,\os,...,\ol} %clip with same path as the outer drawing
  {arc (\i:\i+\a:\R)        --++ (0,0,\h) arc (\i+\a:\i+2*\a:\R) --++ (0,0,-\h)}
   arc (135-2*\a:135-\a:\R) --++ (0,0,\h) arc (135-\a:135:\R)    --++ (0,0,\H-\h)
   arc (135:-45:\R) -- cycle;
\draw[cut] (-45:\R) ++(0,0, 0.8*\H) arc (-45:135:\R);
\draw[cut] (-45:\R) ++(0,0, 0.6*\H) arc (-45:135:\R);
\draw[cut] (-45:\R) ++(0,0, 0.4*\H) arc (-45:135:\R);
\draw[cut] (-45:\R) ++(0,0, 0.2*\H) arc (-45:135:\R);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0, \H) circle (\r);
\clip (135:\r) foreach\i in {135,\is,...,\il} %clip with same path as the inner drawing
  {arc (\i:\i+\a:\r)        --++ (0,0,\h) arc (\i+\a:\i+2*\a:\r) --++ (0,0,-\h)}
   arc (315-2*\a:315-\a:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) arc (315-\a:315:\r)    --++ (0,0, \H-\h)
   arc (315:135:\r) -- cycle;
\draw[cut] (-45:\r) ++(0,0, 0.8*\H) arc (135:-45:-\r);
\draw[cut] (-45:\r) ++(0,0, 0.6*\H) arc (135:-45:-\r);
\draw[cut] (-45:\r) ++(0,0, 0.4*\H) arc (135:-45:-\r);
\draw[cut] (-45:\r) ++(0,0, 0.2*\H) arc (135:-45:-\r);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Stator with red cuts]

Answer (score 0):

The c) image. Only missing the interrupt in the cog gaps in the most below line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

% isometric axes
\pgfmathsetmacro\xx{1/sqrt(2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xy{1/sqrt(6)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zz{sqrt(2/3)}
\tikzset{isometric/.style={x={(-\xx cm,-\xy cm)},y={(\xx cm,-\xy cm)},z={(0cm,\zz cm)}}}

% parameters
\def\nc{24}   % number of cogs (multiple of 4, at least 8)
\def\H {1}    % total height
\def\h {0.25} % cog height
\def\R {2}    % outer radius
\def\r {1.5}  % inner radius

\pgfmathtruncatemacro\nw{\nc/4} % number of cog walls per quadrant
\pgfmathsetmacro\a {180/\nc}    % step angle
\pgfmathsetmacro\is{135+2*\a}   % inner part step
\pgfmathsetmacro\il{315-4*\a}   % inner part last iteration
\pgfmathsetmacro\os{-45+2*\a}   % outer part step
\pgfmathsetmacro\ol{135-4*\a}   % outer part last iteration

\tikzset
{
  inner/.style={fill=gray!30},
  outer/.style={fill=gray!10},
  cogs/.style= {fill=gray!50},
  top/.style=  {fill=gray!20},
  cut/.style=  {color=red!60, dashed},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=1,xscale=1, isometric,line join=round,line cap=round]
% inner cogs side walls
\foreach\i in{-\nw,...,\nw}
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\j{4*\nw-\i}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\k{6*\nw+\i}
  \draw[cogs] (\a*\j:\R) -- (\a*\j:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\j:\R-\r) -- cycle;
  \draw[cogs] (\a*\k:\R) -- (\a*\k:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\k:\R-\r) -- cycle;
}
% inner part
\draw[inner] (135:\r) foreach\i in {135,\is,...,\il}
  {arc (\i:\i+\a:\r)        --++ (0,0,\h) arc (\i+\a:\i+2*\a:\r) --++ (0,0,-\h)}
   arc (315-2*\a:315-\a:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) arc (315-\a:315:\r)    --++ (0,0, \H-\h)
   arc (315:135:\r) -- cycle;
% outer cogs side walls
\foreach\i in{-\nw,...,\nw}
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\j{-\i+2*\nw}
  \draw[cogs] (\a*\i:\R) -- (\a*\i:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\i:\R-\r) -- cycle;
  \draw[cogs] (\a*\j:\R) -- (\a*\j:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\j:\R-\r) -- cycle;
}
% outer part
\draw[outer] (-45:\R) foreach\i in {-45,\os,...,\ol}
  {arc (\i:\i+\a:\R)        --++ (0,0,\h) arc (\i+\a:\i+2*\a:\R) --++ (0,0,-\h)}
   arc (135-2*\a:135-\a:\R) --++ (0,0,\h) arc (135-\a:135:\R)    --++ (0,0,\H-\h)
   arc (135:-45:\R) -- cycle;


% top part
\draw[even odd rule,top] (0,0,\H) circle (\R) (0,0,\H) circle (\r);

\begin{scope}
\clip (\R,\R, \H) circle (1.5*\R);
\draw[even odd rule,cut] (0,0, 0.75*\H) circle (\R);
\draw[even odd rule,cut] (0,0, 0.5*\H) circle (\R);
\clip (\R,\R, \H) circle (1.2*\R);
\draw[even odd rule,cut] (0,0, 0.20*\H) circle (\R);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0, \H) circle (\r);
\draw[even odd rule,cut] (0,0, 0.8*\H) circle (\r);
\draw[even odd rule,cut] (0,0, 0.6*\H) circle (\r);
\draw[even odd rule,cut] (0,0, 0.4*\H) circle (\r);
\draw[even odd rule,cut] (0,0, 0.2*\H) circle (\r);
\end{scope}
%\draw[even odd rule,cut] (0,0,\H) circle (0.95*\R);
%\draw[even odd rule,cut] (0,0,\H) circle (0.90*\R);
%\draw[even odd rule,cut] (0,0,\H) circle (0.85*\R);
%\draw[even odd rule,cut] (0,0,\H) circle (0.80*\R);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```